# Unable to get hiddenfield value inside javascript function

Tags: javascript, asp.net, hidden-field

Here is my scenario, 
I have a button and a dropdownlist inside a page. On clicking of that button I need to open telerik's radwindow. Inside that window I have a gridview,and isnide that grid I need to display hiddenfield's data. Simple enough !!

Here is my mark up of radwindow and grid(Hiddenfield is inside contenttemplate)..

```
<telerik:RadWindow ID="rw_UoMGroupDetails" runat="server" AutoSize="true" MaxHeight="260px" MinWidth="500px" Behaviors="Close,Move" Modal="true" CenterIfModal="true" VisibleTitlebar="true"
    Title="Group Definition" BorderStyle="None" VisibleStatusbar="false" RestrictionZoneID="MainArea">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hfUoMComb" />
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="Updatepanel2" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <telerik:RadAjaxPanel ID="RadAjaxPanel3" LoadingPanelID="RadAjaxLoadingPanel1" runat="server">
                    <telerik:RadGrid ID="rgv_UoMDetails" runat="server" OnNeedDataSource="rgv_UoMDetails_NeedDataSource" Width="100%"
                        Height="220px" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" HeaderStyle-Wrap="false" SelectedItemStyle-BackColor="#003366"
                        OnPreRender="rgv_UoMDetails_PreRender" OnBatchEditCommand="rgv_UoMDetails_BatchEditCommand">
                        <GroupingSettings CollapseAllTooltip="Collapse all groups"></GroupingSettings>
                        <MasterTableView CommandItemDisplay="Top" ShowHeadersWhenNoRecords="true" EditMode="Batch"
                            AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="UoMGID" TableLayout="Fixed">
                            <BatchEditingSettings EditType="Row" />
                            <Columns>
                                <telerik:GridNumericColumn DataField="AltQty" DecimalDigits="5" HeaderText="Alt. Qty" HeaderStyle-Width="100px"
                                    UniqueName="AltQty" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right">
                                </telerik:GridNumericColumn>
                                <telerik:GridTemplateColumn DataField="UoMID" HeaderText="Alt. UoM" HeaderStyle-Width="120px"
                                    UniqueName="AltUoMID">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <%#Eval("AltUoMCode") %>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                    <EditItemTemplate>
                                        <telerik:RadComboBox ID="cmbx_AltUoM" runat="server" Width="100%" Filter="Contains" MarkFirstMatch="true"
                                            OnClientDropDownOpening="onUoMComboItemRequesting">
                                        </telerik:RadComboBox>
                                    </EditItemTemplate>
                                </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                                <telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderStyle-Width="20px" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <span>=</span>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                                <telerik:GridNumericColumn DataField="BaseQty" DecimalDigits="5" HeaderStyle-Width="100px" HeaderText="Base Qty"
                                    UniqueName="BaseQty" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right">
                                </telerik:GridNumericColumn>
                                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="BaseUoMCode" HeaderStyle-Width="100px" FilterControlAltText="Filter BaseUoMCode column"
                                    HeaderText="Base UoM" UniqueName="BaseUoMCode" ReadOnly="true" DefaultInsertValue="Kg">
                                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                            </Columns>
                            <CommandItemSettings AddNewRecordText="" CancelChangesText="" SaveChangesText="" RefreshText="" />
                        </MasterTableView>
                        <ClientSettings AllowKeyboardNavigation="true">
                            <ClientEvents OnBatchEditOpening="BatchEditOpening"></ClientEvents>
                            <Scrolling AllowScroll="true" UseStaticHeaders="true" ScrollHeight="220px" SaveScrollPosition="true" />
                            <Resizing AllowColumnResize="true"></Resizing>
                        </ClientSettings>
                    </telerik:RadGrid>
                </telerik:RadAjaxPanel>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </ContentTemplate>
</telerik:RadWindow>
```

Okay now let me show you where I am setting hiddenfield's data..

```
protected void imgbtn_UoMGroupDef_Click(object sender, ImageButtonClickEventArgs e)
        {
            ViewState["UoMGID"] = cmbx_UoMGGroup.SelectedValue;
            hfUoMComb.Value = cmbx_InventoryUoM.SelectedItem.Text;
```

Now I am calling client side event of this grid where I want to display that hiddenfield's data.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function BatchEditOpening(sender, args) {
            debugger;
            for (var i = 0; i < args._tableView._dataItems.length; i++) {
                args._tableView._dataItems[0]._element.cells[4].innerText = document.getElementById('<%= hfUoMComb.ClientID%>').value;
        }
    }
    </script>
```

Here I am getting empty string :( ! How I can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

This is because `webforms` renders the `id` of the hidden field by adding a random string.

To preserve your `id`, you need to add `ClientIDMode="Static"`

And you should use `ClientID` attribute to set your `id`.

Comment: document.getElementById('<%= hfUoMComb.ClientID%>').value , That's not the matter sir :)

Comment: @Nody Using this, will result in a less readable code. Also, your JS code must be in the form or the control. With `clientdidmode=static`, you can put all JS code in a separate file.